# How can I count the number of occurrences on power pivot?

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have this table
Employee ID, Absence type, start date, end date, index, occurrences

[image]

I don't know how to create the DAX so it gives me the number of absence occurrences for an employee id, I'm using power pivot but if this is doable on power query let me know please!

Thank you

Comment: You want to sum occurrences by ID?  Im thinking thats just a re-arrangement of your pivot, but if you want to do in powrequery, then just right click the ID column and group by... then sum the occurrences column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.